# What do I need to install on a WP8 device that capable it to run my app writen by wp8 and SQL Server CE 3.5?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, installation, sql-server-ce-3.5

Please give me link of program that can capable phone wp8 run my application that written by Wp8 and VS.net 2013 and SQL Server CE 3.5.

Please give me link of software that I need to install on the phone.

Comment: You do not need to install anything on the device...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Finally i found reply for my question:*

**Private file–based deployment (deploying the SQL Server Compact DLLs as part of the project)

***Users do not need administrative credentials to install the
   application.
***SQL Server Compact will not be serviced by Microsoft Update.
          Can also use 
***ClickOnce deployment.

To deploy a SQL Server Compact 4.0 database by using private
    file–based deployment

```
    To open the Project Designer, in Solution Explorer/Database Explorer, double-click My Project if you are working on a Visual
Basic project (or Properties if you are working on a C# project).

    Click the Publish tab.

    Click Prerequisites and then clear the check box for SQL Server Compact.

    Close the Project Designer.

    Go to the directory that contains the SQL Server Compact DLLs. These are located in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact
Edition\v4.0.

    Select the seven SQL Server Compact DLLs and copy them:

        Sqlceca40.dll

        Sqlcecompact40.dll

        Sqlceer40EN.dll

        Sqlceme40.dll

        Sqlceoledb40.dll

        Sqlceqp40.dll

        Sqlcese40.dll

    Paste the DLLs into the project in Solution Explorer/Database Explorer.

    Select all seven DLLs in Solution Explorer/Database Explorer and open the Properties window.

    Set the Copy to Output Directory property to Copy if newer.

    This will replace any earlier DLLs in an existing application with the newer ones if the application is updated.

    Click the Show All Files button in Solution Explorer/Database Explorer.

    Expand the References node.

    Select System.Data.SqlServerCe.

    Set the Copy Local property to True.

    Because your development computer has the SqlServerCe DLLs in the global assembly cache, you must configure the application to use
the DLLs in the output directory.

    Right-click the project in Solution Explorer/Database Explorer and select Publish to open the Publish Wizard.

    Complete the wizard to publish the application.

The application is ready to be installed. Go to the location you
published to, and install the application to verify.
```

Comment: This does not apply to Windows Phone at all

Comment: Are you sure? its my own question and i find answer it in this link of Microsoft. please look at this website :   [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Comment: @ErikEJ i know you make the best component. please tell me now , whats wrong in this reply that i see in MSDN ? thank for your comments .

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server CE is not explicitly supported on Windows Phone. Silverlight-based apps can use LINQ-to-SQL though. See [Local database for Windows Phone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202860(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: yes i know. i use linq to sql and my dabase is sql ce. my question is other thing.

Comment: please tell me what software need install on my device with OS wp8 that make me capable to run own application?

Comment: You need to explain your problem in more detail. What have you tried that doesn't work?

Comment: i don't have cellphone device. i use Emulator for test my application. i afraid if i send my application to that company in other country  , they can not install it easy !! maybe need other thing requirement software install with my application in device!!

Comment: There are three ways to install: Side-load on developer-unlocked phone using Visual Studio tools; side load via Enterprise hub.; or deliver via the Store